# Javascript window.print() gives me a different output

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying to sort out an issue with printing certain areas of a web app i am working on. The issue is with **highcharts js** which renders its bar charts as `<rect ... />.`

On calling the window.print() on load the print call acts just like the background image issue where the background image/colour always disappear. However, when i print the page from the browser menu its displaying as it should be. Any idea why it won't print `<rect />` ?

Comment: Do you have a print stylesheet ?

Comment: Joza, use the backtick `\`` around inline code

Comment: AFAIK, most browsers provide a "print background images" option in the print dialog/browser settings which determines whether the background is printed or not. Does this matter in your case?

Comment: @Salman Since this is a web app, i can't have it depending on the client/customer.

Comment: does enabling "print background images" fixes the problem? If so, you can use CSS positioning to put the image in the foreground but still have it appear behind the bars... its like having two layers in photoshop. Images inside `<img/>` tags should print as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a timing problem. Try something like

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.focus();
    window.print();
}
```

Comment: Hm no, that didn't work besides i am already calling it via <body onload="window.print()">

Comment: Hmm... I added a focus call to try to emulate what happens when you click print in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction the problem seems to be with the timing, window.focus() didn't work though. Using a settimeout worked. :-)

Comment: If this is not the correct answer, can you post the right answer and mark it or edit this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print SVG from all browsers and from the ones you can, the svg needs to have rendered before you try to print it.

I read [here](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) an alternative

> From version 2.0 an exporting module
>   is available for Highcharts, which
>   allows users to download images or
>   PDF's of your charts. This module
>   consists of an extra JavaScript file,
>   exporting.js, and a web service or
>   server module written in PHP.
>   Highslide Software offers the
>   exporting web service free of charge.
>   If you include the exporting module in
>   your charts, two buttons will appear
>   in the upper right. One button prints
>   the chart, which is done on the client
>   side only. The other button handles
>   exporting. By default, an SVG
>   representation of the chart is sent by
>   POST to http://export.highcharts.com,
>   where it is converted using Apache's
>   Batik converter to PDF, PNG or JPEG.

Comment: I have already considered this option but i don't want the data to go to a third party server. Also, an alternative method i did find out was to have the code hosted on my server send the export code to the url,save the image and then use it to print the chart - I am putting this off as a last resort